# Why would a goal of DLP solution implementation include "loss of mitigation"?

Tags: dlp, ccsp

I'm studying for the CCSP exam and a practice question read:

> The goals of DLP solution implementation include all of the following,
>   except:
>
> A. Policy enforcement
>   B. Elasticity
>   C. Data discovery
>   D. Loss of mitigation

I chose D because I don't see how a DLP solution could make mitigation worse...

According to the test prep book though, the answer is B because:

> DLP does not have anything to do with elasticity, which is the
>   capability of the environment to scale up or down according to demand.
>   All the rest are goals of DLP implementations.

OK, fair enough.  I clearly see how I was wrong on the elasticity point.  But why is D not a valid answer?  I reviewed the prep material again and don't see this explained.  Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was probably a typo. Data Loss mitigation is obviously a goal of DLP. Elasticity, as you said, is not a goal of DLP.

Comment: These tests never have typos and factual errors in them! Surely you jest!